# IllegalAccessError: tried to access field android.os.Looper.sThreadLocal from class org.greenrobot.eventbus.android.AndroidDependenciesDetector

Tags: java, android

This is the first time I've used the code obfuscation feature provided by Android Studio, and I got a bug. When I enabled code obfuscation, the compilation run reported an error.If I turn off code obfuscation, it works fine.How can I solve this problem?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.systemui, PID: 10439
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field android.os.Looper.sThreadLocal from class org.greenrobot.eventbus.android.AndroidDependenciesDetector
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.android.AndroidDependenciesDetector.isAndroidSDKAvailable(AndroidDependenciesDetector.java:12)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.android.AndroidComponents.<clinit>(AndroidComponents.java:11)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.Logger$Default.get(Logger.java:65)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBusBuilder.getLogger(EventBusBuilder.java:157)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.<init>(EventBus.java:114)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.<init>(EventBus.java:110)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.getDefault(EventBus.java:88)
    at com.android.systemui.MainActivity.registerEventBus(MainActivity.java:81)
    at com.android.systemui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5281)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error points to registering the Eventbus method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    registerEventBus();
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    init();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SystemService.class);
    startService(intent);


}

private void registerEventBus() {
    if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }
}

@Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(UpdateMessage message){
    EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(message);
    updateTime();
}
```

in build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

in proguard-rules.pro

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }
-keep class android.**{*;}
```